# Issues with connecting to sql server db via linux

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, jdbc

Im trying to execute a jar file from linux.The jar contains java code for connecting to sql server. When I try to execute the jar, Im getting the below error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host servername, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

The connect properties file seems to have a valid username/password. I have checked the sql server configuration manager and the TCP/IP protocol is enabled. Im able to execute the same jar file in winodws and the sql server connection is established fine without any issues. Please let me know the steps I have to take to get this issue resolved.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You said that it works on Windows, was it on the same instance of windows? was it local or over network?

Comment: The db is located in a different windows server machine. It was over network.

Comment: Can you check if you can telnet you server and port on both windows and linux? (tenet <ip address> 1433) Have you checked you firewalls and network conf? is you windows server accessible from your linux?